# Print multiple portions of java JTable to single page

Tags: java, swing, printing

In an application I am currently developing, I have a JTable that gets data from a table model (i have subclassed the DefaultTableModel). When I want to print the JTable I use a modified version of a class that I found online and manage to print it exactly as it appears on the application (using my custom cell renderer).

I wonder though, if anyone can point me on how to print multiple portions of the table in the same page. My table has 3 columns and hundreds of rows. Currently I am printing on each page the three columns and approx. 30 rows. I would like to print to each page two portions, i.e. two pages in one, so that each page has a left part with 3 columns and 30 rows and the right side the 3 columns with the next 30 rows.

Thanx in advance!

Update: Instead of printing:

```
Page 1: 

Col1 | Col2 | Col3
val1 | val2 | val3

Page 2:

Col1 | Col2 | Col3
val4 | val5 | val6
```

I wish to print:

```
Page 1:

Col1 | Col2 | Col3          Col1 | Col2 | Col3
val1 | val2 | val3          val4 | val5 | val6
```

Thanx!!!

Comment: On what page? pc monitor or paper of what format (A4, american letter size). Also would be nice to know what are you using at the moment for printing as to provide more specific answer

Comment: A4 format, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: hmm .. I don't see how that is a problem of your _table printing_: wouldn't you simply set-up the printer to print two pages on one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check this tutorial [Printing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html), (there is way) how to create custom formated previue just for printOut

Comment: ahh another stalker from daniweb :p

Comment: I am currently using custom format for printing. What I am looking for (and I am not sure if it exists) is maybe an automated way to print two pages at one when a JTable needs a mutlipage output.

Comment: is that solve??? this tutorial contains JTable printing examples http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html for 90degrees rotate you have to look for PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE); myTable.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, null, null, false, set, false);

Answer (score 1):

I while back I was looking for a ready API myself. I found nothing that would do what I want for free.

Thus I think you will have to handle it yourself. You need to make appropriate calculations yourself.

For example:

- you need to know how many pages it will take under normal conditions.
- then you evaluate how much space you need for a single page on the printout page.
- then you move translate your graphics, scaling accordingly so it will fit right.

I would suggest you try first with only a single dimension, e.g. scale only height so it fits one under another, do not worry about width scaling for the first time.

Hope it is any help to you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact I was searching also for a free library to do that but I will follow your guidelines and try to implement it myself.